# Is there any reason to quote the placeholder in a find ... -exec command_to_run {} \; statement?

Tags: shell, find, quotes

I occasionally see people wrap the placeholder (`{}`) in single quotes. This is probably because it is used as an example in the GNU `find` manual.

> `find . -type f -exec file '{}' \;`

Runs `file' on every file in or below the current directory.  **Notice that the braces are enclosed in single quote marks  to  protect  them  from  interpretation  as  shell  script punctuation**.  The semicolon is similarly protected by the use of a backslash, though single quotes could have been used in that case also.

Filenames containing `<space>`, `<newline>`, `<tab>`, `|`, `&`, `;`, `<`, `>`, `(`, `)`, `$`, `` ` ``, `\`, `"`, `'`, `*`, `?`, `[`, `#`, `~`, `=`, `%`, `{` and `}` are all handled correctly on GNU and FreeBSD `find`, regardless of whether or not the placeholder is wrapped in single quotes.

Is the example shown in the GNU `find` manual a case of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)? Is single quoting the placeholder covering some edge case I am unaware of, or is it a waste of quotes?

Comment: I guess you mean something like `find .... -exec ..... '{}' .... \;` ? I never do this quoting, and I don't remember having ever seen it quoted. Of course quoting would make sense if we want to pass a longer string which is *containing* the placeholder, i.e. `.... -exec ..... 'x y {} z' ... \;`.

Comment: This question has been answered excellently on [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8647/gnu-find-and-masking-the-for-some-shells-which)

Answer (score 2):

In the `EXAMPLES` section of the GNU `find` man pages, one can find the following sentence:

> ```
> find . -type f -exec file '{}' \;
> ```
>
> Runs  `file' on every file in or below the current directory.  **Notice that the braces are enclosed in single quote marks to protect them from interpretation as shell script punctuation.**  The semicolon is similarly protected by the use of a backslash, though single quotes could have been used in that case also.

I couldn't come up with an example where `{}` without quote breaks the `-exec` command, even with spaces or control character in the filename.

However if you append a string to the filename, you may need to quote the expression if that string can be interpreted by the shell.

For example adding a `$` in front of the filename would break in the following case:

```
find . -type f -exec echo ${} \;
```

whereas it wouldn't break if the expression is quoted":

```
find . -type f -exec echo '${}' \;
```

Comment: Any idea what is "shell script punctuation"?

Comment: @adosar The semi-colon `;` is one (that's the end of a shell statement)

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are using a POSIX compliant shell, there is no reason to quote the placeholder (`{}`). If you are using fish or the rc shell, you need to quote the placeholder to prevent expansion. Allegedly, there may be certain non-modern csh variants that require the placeholder to be quoted. Check out the awesome answers for [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8647/gnu-find-and-masking-the-for-some-shells-which) on Unix & Linux that do more justice than I ever could.